# Copying children of a <ul> to another <ul> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I copy copy content of a `ul` that is `li`'s inside it to another `ul`.

Say we have `t = $("ul#target")` and `s = $("ul#source")`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the children then use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to put them on the destination `<ul>`, like this:

```
$("#source").children().clone().appendTo("#target");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.children().clone().appendTo(t)
```